# Google maps api, select infowindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im sorry  for a bad title..

But now to the problem: Im using google maps api, everything works just fine

except this [image]

As you see, i don't get the title to show, unless i scroll up at the map.. Anyone knows how i can center this instead so the info window is more visible?

```
  function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.671431,14.976811);
  var myMaplng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.671828,14.976794);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: myMaplng,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content" style="padding: 0;margin:0;">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" style="padding: 0;margin:0;">lololol</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p>Kaserngatan 24A<br>575 34 sdad<br></p>På den här addressen ligger vårat temporära kontor.. ' + 
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'lololol'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(window, 'load', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Could you provide information about styling of your page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Info Window wrong size on Google Maps API v3 Street View Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168886/info-window-wrong-size-on-google-maps-api-v3-street-view-service)

Comment: Thats not a duplicate.. Thats not even my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is to pan the marker to the bottom of the map to show more of the InfoWindow.

Checkout line 37 of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victoryismine06/sLftX/1/) to see how [map.panBy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en) works..

`map.panBy(x:number, y:number)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/sLftX/), but I am not able to reproduce it.  However I guess somewhere in your CSS is getting overridden.

Anyway Google maps provided an option to programatically move the map using **`panTo(latLng)`** method.

> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is
>   less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be
>   smoothly animated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that height of your map is too small. Check your styling, there should be something in your file like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map { height: 50%; width: 80% }
</style>
```

or

```
<body>
    <div id="map" style='height:50%;width:80%'/>
</body>
```

If you increase `height` there will be more place for your infowindow.

You can make width of infowindow larger but in your case it won't help much. For example:

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });
```

You can also move infowindow down using `pixelOffset` option:

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 50)
  });
```

but in that case your marker won't be visible until you close infowindow.